# "Openned text" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a piece of text, and I don't really get what it is saying, especially the "opened text" part

> While there is indeed much to learn from many species not yet known to science, it's the already opened texts that attract the majority of us, however. And we are attracted in ever increasing numbers.

Comment: not known -> (text)book that's closed; already known -> book that's open.  Clear now?

Answer (score 0):

The text is suggesting that it is the case that a majority of people are attracted to the study of already researched species - there would be a lot to learn from studying species which have not been previously researched.

Comment: The quote doesn't assign a judgement, it only describes the state as it is.